# How can I only use core Node.js to check up the filesystems status.( as 'df' command )

Tags: node.js

i want to implement a node.js program to checkup the filesystems(such as ext3..)status. However, the fs module only provide the operations of file. Must i use something else third part module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to  capture the output of the 'df' command and parse it.

You can run commands using child processes.
http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_processes.html#child_process.exec

```
var child_process = require('child_process');

child_process.exec('df', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  // 'stdout' here is a string containing the things printed by 'df'
  console.log(stdout);
});
```